# AngularJs form not displaying form data pushed to a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I made a simple AnguarJS app with form and list of books. In list of books I have a form, in which I can type information about book and submit, and my list of book should change. I want to make something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_app4

But when I add information in form, I don't see added infromatioin in book-list, but only empty field. I don't want to send information to the server, I only want to see added information on the web-page. Files, that I use are below:

**app.js**

```
var module = angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute']);
module.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
})
module.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/route1', {
                templateUrl: 'static/myapp/html/test1.html',
                controller: 'RouteController1'
            }).
            when('/route2', {
                templateUrl: 'static/myapp/html/test2.html',
                controller: 'BookController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);
module.controller('BookController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.books = [
{
    title: 'test',
    author: 'test',


}
];
$scope.addMe = function (title, author) { 
    $scope.books.push({title: title, author: author});
}

}]);
```

**test2.html**

```
<div class="container">
<div ng-controller="BookController" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat = "book in books">
            Title:<p>[[book.title]] </p>
            Author: <p>[[book.author]] </p>     

        </li>    
    </ul>

    <input type="text"  placeholder = 'title'/>
    <input type="text" placeholder = 'author'/>
    <button ng-click="addMe(title,author)">Add</button>

</div>

</div>
```

After filling form I get the next result:
[image: res]

Comment: Why you are adding controller two times (1: on route and 2 . Inline )? Also where is ur text box bindings ..

Comment: @Venkat I add two controllers, because I have an index.html where I have links to test1.html(controller 1), and test2.html(controller 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because you don't set variable.
You add title and author in `addMe` but if you `console.log` these variables, it shows `undefined`.

You can use $scope. You can see it as the bridge between the controller and the view. So, in your view, when you set the title and the author and click on `addMe`, you will get it in the controller in `$scope.title` and `scope.author`

in the view.

`<input type="text"  placeholder = 'title' ng-model="title"/>
 <input type="text" placeholder = 'author' ng-model="author"/>
 <button ng-click="addMe()">Add</button>`

In the controller just after the books declaration:

`$scope.title = '';
$scope.author = '';`

In `addMe`

`$scope.books.push({title: $scope.title, author: $scope.author});`

Comment: thaks for your answer, it helps, all works! But why I should write `$scope.title=''` after books declaration, but not `$scope.books.title=''` ?

Comment: Because you use `$scope.title` and `$scope.author` as a temporary variable. $scope.books.title will not works because it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `$scope.books` to a new array instead of pushing to it. Angular.js checks which variables have changed by comparing references. Since the variable `book` stays set to the same array, angular's dirty checking feature might not detect a new element.

Change it to something like this

`$scope.books = $scope.books.concat([{title: title, author: author}]);`

This should work because concat returns a new array instead of updating the old one.

Comment: In my case I should push each element to end of the array, but concat() method can only concatenate two arrays, if I understand correctly.